Why is the type for `block` param passed to `launch` function marked both `suspend` and an extension on `CouroutineScope`
The function signature for launch function as per official doc is like
fun CoroutineScope.launch(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext, 
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT, 
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
): Job

where the block parameter is marked both suspend and a extension on CoroutineScope
Roman Elizarov in the article explains why function should either be marked suspend or an extension on CourotineScope but not both.
Excerpt from the article
If you need to launch a coroutine that keeps running after your function returns, then make your function an extension of CoroutineScope or pass scope: CoroutineScope as parameter to make your intent clear in your function signature. Do not make these functions suspending
My question - Why is this not the case for the lambda passed to coroutine builder functions?

This means that a suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit suspending lambda can be called only from a CoroutineScope. Take a look at this example, which explains the mechanics of the coroutineScope function and its semantics in the Kotlin's structured concurrency.

Does kotlinx coroutines framework ensure that when the control returns from the block all the child coroutines started from within the block are also completed? In other words is it ensured that block gets executed inside the scope created by coroutineScope?

There are no guarantees. This function returns as soon as the given block and all its child coroutines are completed. When any child coroutine in this scope fails, the whole scope fails, cancelling all the other children (if you need another behavior, see supervisorScope).

Is it correct to say that when the block passed to launch completes its execution, there could still be some coroutines (started within the block) that are not yet finished? If so, doesn’t this contradict the suggestion in the article that a function marked with suspend should complete without leaving any side effects of launching any concurrent work and they should wait for for all their work to complete before returning to the caller?

I think, yes "...there could still be some coroutines that are not yet finished...".  I forwarded this comment to Roman Elizarov.
